# BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted close form

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to close a dialog (used to upload a file) after a `BackgroundWorker` has completed (`RunWorkerCompleted`) its tasks.

Right now my `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler looks like this:

```
private void uploadWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Hide the loading popup.
    loadingScreenDialog.Hide();

    // Close the dialog.
    this.Close();
}
```

It doesn't close the form, yet it hides the loading popup, so the `DoWork` handler was executed successfully.

Why is my form not being closed?

**EDIT**

I eventually fixed the problem by removing some operations from my `DoWork` handler and it worked. Dirty work-around, thanks for helping me though.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This should work. Do you have a `FormClosing` event handler that is setting `e.Cancel` to `true`?

Comment: No I do not. I have no `FormClosing` handler.